# Java Android, putting hint/description on object methods/functions

Tags: java

As title how would I place a hint or description on the object so that if a user hovers over the method or object they'll get a description much like the standard library of objects that have explanations. I've searched everywhere but I'm unable to find an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use JavaDoc comments, something like:

```
/**
 * This method returns the x value.
 * 
 * @return the x value
 */
public int getValue()
{
    return x;
}
```

For more on this, see: [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the use of JavaDoc.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Example from the page above:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

Additionally, you'll need an IDE that supports this, e.g. Eclipse.